# mySQL search not really working

Tags: php, mysql, search

Here is a mySQL query with the password and usernames deliberately botched out. It is returning only one result is not returning any other information than today's date for that one result. It does not matter what search one tries it is not functioning.

```
 <?php 

    $proto = $_GET['p'];
    $terms = $_GET['f'];
    $return;

    if($proto == 'inline'){
        echo 'checking';
    $username="*******";
    $password="*******";
    $database="*******";
    $my_text = $_GET['f'];        //what I'm searching for
    $my_category = '8';        //whatever category number it is

    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$my_text%' ");
    // select all posts that have your text

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));

    $postname = $row['post_name'];
    $posttitle = $row['post_title'];
    $postID = $row['ID']; 
    $date = date ( 'd-M-Y' , strtotime($row['post_date']) );

        $return.= '
                    <a href="http://www.robin-knight.com/' . $postname .'">'.$posttitle.' ('.$postname.')<br /><span style="font-size:10px; color:#555;">'.get_the_time("d-M-Y", $postID).' - '.get_post_meta($postID, "status", true).'</span></a>
                ';

       //while have posts

       echo $return;

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Time to learn how SQL works, I think...

Comment: What's your question? Also, what does "not really working" mean?

Comment: Nice SQL injection holes. Hope you like the truck that someone'll park in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other information:

I might be missing it, but I don't see you encompassing anything in your while loop.

That would be why it's only getting one.  You need to use braces { }

Comment: I think that may be a typo in the question, but it's a good point.

Comment: @Robin Knight -- if that was the error, you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not select `post_name`, `post_title`, or `post_date`. You said `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts`, so it selected ID and nothing else, as instructed. Your `date()` call sort of works because `strtotime()` is returning false, so it uses today's date as a fallback.

Comment: If you need `post_name`, you're going to have to select it. `SELECT ID, post_name, post_title, post_date FROM wp_posts ...`.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$my_text%' ");
```

is very unsafe - `my_text` isn't escaped, and is taken from GET params, so it opens you to a SQL Injection attack. Escape it using `mysql_real_escape_string`, or, better yet, use parametrized queries in your code.

Comment: That is an absolutely brilliant answer to my question